# Пчихати, чихати і чхати

Tags: вибір-слова

Я завжди думав, що потрібно вживати слово "[чхати](http://sum.in.ua/s/chkhaty)", однак невдовдзі дізнався, що є синоніми до даного дієслова - "[пчихати](http://sum.in.ua/s/pchykhaty)" та "[чихати](http://sum.in.ua/s/chykhaty)". От цікавить чи можна їх вживати, наприклад у творах ЗНО, адже вони є у СУМі, однак мають позначку "рідко" та "розмовне", а також, на мою думку. Крім того, в [Гугл перекладачі](https://translate.google.com/?hl=uk#ru/uk/%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C) при перекладі російського слова "чихать" дається тільки два варіанта "чхати" та "начхати".

Отож, яке з цих трьох слів краще вживати чи можна вживати кожне з них не боючись зробити помилку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Коло слова **пчихати** бачимо позначку ***розм.***. У
писемній
мові
вживання
слів
розмовної
лексики
до
певної
міри
[обмежене](http://kulturamovy.univ.kiev.ua/KM/pdfs/Magazine2-1.pdf)
  —  вони
будуть
недоречними
у
науковому
творі
, 
в
ділових
паперах
тощо.
Тому це слово вживати, наприклад, у творах ЗНО, не можна.

При слові **чихати** бачимо позначку ***рідко***, що вказує на те, що його потрібно вживати з обережністю. Твори на ЗНО - це досить шаблонна система, де викладачі радять учням не писати неоднозначних тверджень (наприклад, глибоко не "влізати" в політичні і релігійні питання), оскільки перевірятиметься все це без вашої присутності і довести правильність своєї думки неможливо (хіба що апеляція). Тому, в творах ЗНО, на мою думку, вживати цього слова не варто.

Біля слова **чхати** не має ніякої позначки, тому можна сміливо його вживати.